# Firefox: Remember new passwords without prompting

Tags: firefox, passwords, password-management

How can I make Firefox automatically remember all passwords without prompting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hacking Firefox to Always Auto Save Password Without Showing Notification Bar:**

1. Close Firefox
2. Edit nsLoginManagerPrompter.js with notepad which is normally located in C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\components\
3. Replace the entire lines **642 to 711** with the code below:

   ```
   var pwmgr = this._pwmgr;
   pwmgr.addLogin(aLogin);
   ```

[image]

Now whenever you login to any website, Firefox will auto save the site, username and password to the login manager WITHOUT showing the notification bar.

*Note: even when you enter the wrong username or password, it will still be saved.*

*[Source](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/11/05/hacking-firefox-to-always-auto-save-password-without-showing-notification-bar/)*

Comment: This is one reason why I'm glad it prompts me - so I can wait to say "yes" after I see that the login was correct.

Comment: if the prompt is about "changing password", did that update it without notifications ?

Comment: well, you can always delete wrong user names/passwords from the password manager.

Comment: @Molly, but that is more of a pain, than dealing with the occasional pop-down notification.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this site here has the answer you are looking for [here](http://www.optimiced.com/en/2008/08/13/make-firefox-remember-all-passwords/).

It states that you must have all instances of Firefox closed, navigate to the "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\components\" directory, open up nsLoginManager.js and comment out lines 112 and 121.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox 4

- Extract omni.jar located in the Firefox folder and then open the components folder
- Edit what you need
- Then compress it, using zip format or it will not work, and name it omni.jar
- Note: Don't compress the folder "omni". Compress what's inside the folder
- Replace your omni.jar with the one in the Firefox folder

Answer (score 1):

This DOES still work in Firefox 3.6 - 4.0+, it's just not in the same place as shown in the picture.

**Using Firefox 4.0:**

Edit `nsLoginManagerPrompter.js` which is normally located in `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\components\`.

Replace the code from lines 800 - 869 with:

```
var pwmgr = this._pwmgr; pwmgr.addLogin(aLogin);
```

Save and replace original file.

Et voila!

Saves passwords and doesn't prompt.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac Firefox 3.6, the edits are made in:

- In the finder, go to the Applications folder
- Firefox (right click and select "show package contents")
- Navigate to *Contents* ? *MacOS* ? *Components*
- The file has the same name: nsLoginManagerPrompter.js
- MAKE A BACKUP COPY OF THIS FILE! But you knew that :-)
- Edit lines 815 through the end of the function - 850.

Here's my change complete - which make the end line 854.

```
    var pwmgr = this._pwmgr;

    // phil
    pwmgr.addLogin(aLogin);

    /* phil
        var buttons = [
            // "Remember" button
            {
                label:     rememberButtonText,
                accessKey: rememberButtonAccessKey,
                popup:     null,
                callback: function(aNotificationBar, aButton) {
                    pwmgr.addLogin(aLogin);
                }
            },

            // "Never for this site" button
            {
                label:     neverButtonText,
                accessKey: neverButtonAccessKey,
                popup:     null,
                callback: function(aNotificationBar, aButton) {
                    pwmgr.setLoginSavingEnabled(aLogin.hostname, false);
                }
            },

            // "Not now" button
            {
                label:     notNowButtonText,
                accessKey: notNowButtonAccessKey,
                popup:     null,
                callback:  function() { /* NOP * / }
            }
        ];

        this._showLoginNotification(aNotifyBox, "password-save",
                                    notificationText, buttons);
    */
},
```

I kept everything but commented out what I didn't want (`/* ... */`), and added the `pwmgr.addLogin(aLogin)` line.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient question but here is a guide for Firefox 71.0.

First of all we need to extract archive which contains all the password manager JavaScript. It is **omni.ja** in Firefox **main installation directory**. To find out how to extract and pack it back look at the [official documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_(formerly_omni.jar)) (you can use [latest version of 7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) to do it).

Once you have it extracted look at these functions and edit them (line number, name). You need basic knowledge of JavaScript for that.

```
modules/LoginManagerPrompter.jsm
1426    _showSaveLoginDialog
946     promptToSavePassword
422     promptUsernameAndPassword
552     promptPassword
669     promptAuth

modules/LoginManagerParent.jsm
571     async onFormSubmit
```

When you edit these functions you can repack the file back with command mentioned in documentation (repacking it other way might not work, zip command is for Unix only):

```
zip -qr9XD omni.ja *
```

Now every password will get saved even when Firefox is set to ignore certain site.